# How to remove Google Play sample books from my library without them coming back?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-books

I have the Google Play Books app on my Android tablet, and there are three books included with it: Alice in Wonderland, The Three Musketeers, and Treasure Island. When I go to my library and hit the three-dot icon, then Delete from library, it removes them.

However, in about 2-5 minutes, I get a notification that they were added to my library, and when I look back in, they're there once again. How do I make them go away?

Answer (score 4):

Go to [Google Play Books](https://play.google.com/books), find the book(s), click on the menu (three vertical dots), choose "Remove from my library", and agree to the confirmation that pops up.

The books should now be gone from your library and will, once your device syncs, be gone from the device as well.

Comment: Did you mean to go to the site on my PC?

Comment: I tried that and it did remove them. I don't know if it will stay gone in a few minutes.

Comment: @Pho Yes, although the browser in your phone should suffice.

Comment: It just opens the app when I click the link on my tablet, so I just did it on my PC.

Comment: They came back after opening the Google Play Books app on my tablet again.